# Php array delete in reverse

Tags: php, arrays

I need to delete the values inside the array that are before the given variable and store in the same key, thanks in advance.

```
$filter = 8;

Array
(
    [1] => 
    [2] => 
    [3] => 
    [4] => 
    [5] => 
    [6] => 
    [7] => 
    [8] => 
    [9] => 
    [10] => 
    [11] => 
    [13] => PHM
    [14] => PHN
    [15] => N
    [17] => M9
    [18] =>

)
```

My output should be,

```
Array(
    [8] => 
    [9] => 
    [10] => 
    [11] => 
    [13] => PHM
    [14] => PHN
    [15] => N
    [17] => M9
    [18] =>
)
```

Comment: tried but keys are going different. Array ( [0] => [1] => [2] => [3] => PHM [4] => PHN [5] => N [6] => M9 )

Comment: How have you used the function?

Comment: array_slice($table_list, $filter);

Comment: Well just do: `print_r(array_slice($table_list, $filter));`

Comment: Array
(
    [0] => 
    [1] => 
    [2] => 
    [3] => PHM
    [4] => PHN
    [5] => N
    [6] => M9
)    same only

Comment: Your array starts with 1 and not 0, so you have to set the argument to true to keep the index, so: `print_r(array_slice($table_list, $filter, NULL, TRUE));`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`array_slice()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) to do this. Now since you don't have a 0-based enumerated array, you have to make sure to set the 
preserve_keys parameter to true:

```
print_r(array_slice($table_list, $filter, NULL, TRUE));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$arr = array("","","","","","","","","","","","","","PHM","PHN","N","","M9","");
$filter = 8;
For($i=0;$i<$filter;$i++){
    If(isset($arr[$i])) unset($arr[$i]);
}

Var_dump($arr);
```

I created an array with all indexes, for this example, but it will work even if 0 and 12 is missing because of isset().

https://3v4l.org/WKMGO

Edited to keep key 8.